# The location of figure in PNAS template mess up caption and legend

Tags: captions, legend, pnas

I am modifying this PNAS template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas) for my journal. I have been puzzled by the position of figure and its effects on caption position and legend indentation for the whole day.  The template says `Be sure to add figures and tables after \end{article} and before \end{document}`. If following this instruction, the figure caption and legend are fine (see next figure).

[image]

However, for my own journal, I want the figures be in the middle of the article (before `\end{article}`).  Doing this will mess up the figure caption (now below the legend).  In addition, the legend show left indentation.  See next image.

[image]

How to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: PNAS template is here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas

Comment: Are you really sure you want a badly written class such as PNAS as a model?

Comment: So far haven't find a better one. Any suggestions?

Comment: I meant with similar style